# Button not redirecting to the correct page

Tags: javascript, html, mysql, node.js, express

Im trying to make a button save the data from the form into de database and then redirect it to another page but the saving to the database is not working and the redirecting is also not working, this is the form im using.

```html
<div id="newFormPage">
        <form id="useForm">
        <!--barra de topo-->
        <div class="container-fluid">
            <div class="row topbar">
                <div class="col-4"></div>
                <div class="col-1" style="align-content:right;">Template</div>
                <div class="col-2">
                    <select name="Tipos" class="form-control" value="tipo" id="tipo">
                        <option value="nenh">Nenhum</option>
                        <option value="def">Default</option>
                        <option value="inq">Inquérito</option>
                        <option value="ques">Questionario</option>
                        <option value="vot">Votação</option>
                    </select>
                </div>

                <div class="col-1">
                    <button class="btn" id="createbtn"  name="useform" style="background-color: #5e5e5e; color:white;">
                        Usar</button>
                </div>
                <div class="col-4"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <br>
        <br>
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col">
                    //the content here is irrelevant to the problem
                </center>
                </div>
                <div class="col">
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Nome" id="formnome" required>
                    <textarea rows="7" cols="40" maxlength="370" placeholder="Descrição" id="formdesc" required></textarea>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </form>
    </div>
```

This is the controller file im using, i tried to use  window.location.href if the status result was success but it doesn't work

```
 $('#useForm').on('submit', function(e) {
//se submeter com erros
if (e.isDefaultPrevented()) {
    alert("form with errors") // handle the invalid form...
}
//se estiver tudo bem
else {
    console.log("eque");
    event.preventDefault();
    //carregamento dos dados do form para variávels JS
    //como a chamada é feita do lado do cliente o carregamento é com jQuery
    var data = {};
    data.tipo =$("#tipo").val();
    data.formnome = $("#formnome").val();
    data.formdesc = $("#formdesc").val();

    //chamada AJAX para envio dos dados para o servidor via POST convertendo o array em JSON
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: '../useform',
        data: JSON.stringify(data),
        contentType: 'application/json',
        success: function(result) {
            console.log(result);
            //analisa a resposta (res.end) que está no result e se o status for 200 envia um alerta
            if (result.status == 200) {
                window.location.href = "https://ea10-cfportela.c9users.io/criarform";
            }

        },
        error: function(data) { console.log(data) }
    });
}
});
```

This is the routes file.

```
//rota inicial
global.app.get('/criarform', function(req, res) {
console.log('GET /');
//leitura do ficheiro estático - view do user
   var html = global.fs.readFileSync('./view/criar-form.html');
res.writeHead(200, {
    'Content-Type': 'text/html'
});
    res.end(html);
});
    global.app.post('/useform', function(req, res) {
    console.log('body: ' + JSON.stringify(req.body));
    //chamada da função save que está no contacts.model e envio dos parâmetros
    var tipo = global.connect.con.escape(req.body.tipo);
    var nome = global.connect.con.escape(req.body.formnome);
    var desc = global.connect.con.escape(req.body.formedesc);
    global.modelUsarForm.usarform(tipo,nome,desc);
    res.send('{"success" : "Updated Successfully", "status" : 200}');
 });
```

And this is the model file

```
 function usarform(tipo, formnome, formdesc) {
if(tipo == "def"){
    tipo = 1;
}
else if(tipo == "inq"){
    tipo = 2;
}
else if(tipo == "ques"){
    tipo = 3;
}
else if(tipo == "vot"){
    tipo = 4;
}
else if(tipo == "nenh"){
    tipo = 5;
}

 var post = {formdesc: formdesc , formnome: formnome ,id:5, tipo: tipo};
var query = global.connect.con.query('INSERT INTO Formulario SET ?', post, function(err, rows, fields) {
    console.log(query.sql);
    if (!err) {
        console.log("Number of records inserted: " + rows.affectedRows);
    }
    else
        console.log('Error while performing Query.', err);
  });
 }
 //função de leitura que retorna o resultado no callback
  function read(callback) {
  //criar e executar a query de leitura na BD
   global.connect.con.query('SELECT * from Formulario', function(err, rows, 
    fields) {
    if (!err) {
        //gravar os resultados rows no callback
        callback(null, rows);
    }
    else
        console.log('Error while performing Query.', err);
     });
     };
   //exportar as funções
 module.exports = {
     read: read,
     usarform: usarform
 }
```

Comment: You say saving isn't working, so i would guess redirect isn't necessarily broken. You just aren't getting a successful response. Have you tried debugging your model code?

Comment: how is this         url: '../useform',  a valid RESTful url? did you debug your code to see if the AJAX call actually works?

Comment: for what i tested the button isnt even working, i added a console.log right in the begining of the controller and nothing shows up on the console what might be the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're using an old and deprecated way of dealing with submit.

**My solution**

Add an onClick to your button such as this

```
<button onclick="myFunction()">Click me</button>
```

and then your myFunction entails all your form handling and requests to your backend which you've already made

**What's going wrong with your code**

You need to add type="submit" on your button

```
<input type="submit" class="btn" id="createbtn" name="useform" style="background-color: #5e5e5e; color:white;">
  Usar
</input>
```

Comment: so i need to add  both the onclick="myFunction()" to the button and the type="submit"? or i should pick one  of them?

Comment: Pick one of them, both should work but the first solution imo is the best way to go.

Comment: i tried both and problem is still the same nothing happens

Comment: Can you put your code on codesandbox or something? I can then edit it there and find a solution

Comment: not sure if you are going to be able to edit but i think i can add permissions https://ide.c9.io/fajesse/app